# Javascript - constructor cannot be called as a function

Tags: javascript, django

Please, could you tell me what's wrong in this code ?
This is Django framework + JS.

I want to make my div block to be visible when I click on the button.

Everything else is working fine. I mean my loop is ok and `comment.id` returns a unique ID.

When I click on the button, I have a JS error: "constructor cannot be called as a function"

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Comment': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):218)
onclick @ (index):218
(index):218 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Comment': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):218)
onclick @ (index):218
```

My code:

```
  <!-- Button see comments -->
  <button 
    onclick="Comment()" 
    type="button" 
    class="w3-button w3-theme-d1 w3-margin-bottom">
    Commenter
  </button>
  <!-- end button -->

  {%for comment in comments%}

    {%if comment.articles.id == post.id or comment.statut.id == post.id %}   

      <!-- Bloc comments-->
      <div id="{{comment.id}}" style="overflow-wrap: break-word; display: none;" class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin">    
        <p>{{comment.text}}</p>
          <p style="width: 100%; text-align: right;">
            <img alt="Avatar" class="w3-circle-articles" style="vertical-align:middle;" src="{{media}}{{comment.author.profile.avatar}}" />
            <span style="color: #0477BF;"">{{comment.author}}</span> le {{comment.date|date:"d F"}} à {{comment.date|date:"H:m"}}
         </p>                           
      </div> 
      <!-- End bloc comments -->

      <!-- JAVASCRIPT to see comments  -->
      <script type="text/javascript">
        function Comment{{comment.id}}() {
            document.getElementById("{{comment.id}}").style.display = "block";
        }

      </script> 
      <!-- End JAVASCRIPT -->

    {%endif%} 

  {%endfor%}
```

This is what it looks like in HTML when I look at the source code of the page:

```
    <div id="2" style="overflow-wrap: break-word; display: ;" class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin">    
                    <p>lol</p>
                      <p style="width: 100%; text-align: right;">
                        <img alt="Avatar" class="w3-circle-articles" style="vertical-align:middle;" src="http://******/media/user/user_20/avatar/horror-gaming-avatar.png">
                        <span style="color: #0477BF;" "="">Preyor</span> le 10 juillet à 10:07
                     </p>                           
     </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
                function Comment2() {
                    document.getElementById("2").style.display = "block";
                }

                i = i+1
                document.getElementById("Comment_Count3").innerHTML = i;
 </script>

    <div id="3" style="overflow-wrap: break-word; display: ;" class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-round w3-margin">    
                    <p>hihi</p>
                      <p style="width: 100%; text-align: right;">
                        <img alt="Avatar" class="w3-circle-articles" style="vertical-align:middle;" src="http://*********/media/user/user_4/avatar/hebus_1920x1080_1464110916_5053_sMlLt6u.jpg">
                        <span style="color: #0477BF;" "="">GrandGTO</span> le 18 juillet à 02:07
                     </p>                           
     </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function Comment3() {
                        document.getElementById("3").style.display = "block";
                    }

                    i = i+1
                    document.getElementById("Comment_Count3").innerHTML = i;
     </script>
```

Comment: Use a lowercase `C`? `comment()`

Comment: No changment ...

Comment: This is horrible. Why would you define a separate function for each comment? That is what parameters are for.

Comment: Because I am a noob in JS.

Comment: Do you want to show all comments on single button click or you will have separate button to show each comment?

Comment: I have solved my issue. My problem was because my JS function did an action on a div for just one comment. I made a div for the entire comments and now It works. It joins what you told me @ankitchaudhary

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `Comment()` function is **not defined**. Javascript Engine is not able to find definition of `Comment()`.There is definitions for `Comment2()`, `Comment3()`. But no definition for `Comment()`.

```
function Comment{{comment.id}}() { // it should be Comment and not Comment{{comment.id}}
        document.getElementById("{{comment.id}}").style.display = "block";
    }
```